# Adobe Livecycle: how to get the value of process data

Tags: process, adobe, livecycle

I have a process data defined in Adobe livecycle, `addField` as a string. I am passing the value of this variable as an input when i invoke a process. Further i want to compare the value of this process data if it is true or false. I am trying to use the following expression:

```
string(/process_data/@addField)=string("true")
```

but i am not getting the value out of the expression. Is the above expression true? If not what is used to get the value of the process data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your XPath expression is wrong. I just did a quick mock-up in workbench and I got the correct response. Here are the details of what I did:

1. Created an input string variable i workbench called addField.
2. Created a two step process. The first step has two routes going out to two different set values.
3. On one of the routes, I added the following condition:

   /process_data/@addField = "true"
4. Turned on recording, and invoked the process.
5. In the input parameters screen in workbench, I added the following text: true
6. In the recording, I can see the expression evaluating correctly and going to the correct set value.

Do let me know if you have any other questions.

Thanks,
Armaghan.